# How can I get an array of records associated with the records in another array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a model `Item`, which has_many `Votes`. Votes can belong to only one Item. If I have an array of Votes `@votes = Vote.where(ip: "1")`, how can I get an array of the Items associated with the Votes in `@votes`?

For example, if `@votes.first.item.name => "Item1"`, then "Item1" should be the first Item in the new array.

**models**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are using ActiveRecord I would recommend to use it to get your list straightaway like this:

```
@items = Item.joins(:votes).where(votes: {ip: "1"})
```

This way Rails builds a query to get exactly the list of items you are looking for without having to build the list manipulating arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
@votes.map { |item| item.name }
```

You can define [order](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) while doing query itself, e.g.:

```
@votes = Vote.where(ip: "1").order("id desc") # or "id asc"
```